# Trying to Add Episode ID to TV Shows via Applescript in iTunes

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have the following code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
repeat with thetrack in tracks of playlist "foo"
    set showName to name of thetrack
    set showName to ((characters 17 through -1 of showName) as string)
    set episode ID of thetrack to name of thetrack
end repeat
end tell
```

I am trying to set the episode ID of TV Shows to the track name. If I comment out the set episode ID line, showName is definititely set to the correct string. When I try to actually set the episode ID however I get the following error:

> iTunes got an error: Can’t set episode ID of item 1 of every track of playlist "Fitness & Nutrition" to name of item 1 of every track of playlist "Fitness & Nutrition".

I admit, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set episode ID of thetrack to (name of thetrack as text)
```

because

```
return class of name of thetrack --> property
```

and

```
return class of (name of thetrack as text) --> text
```

[image]